# How to use Powershell 7 from AzureDevops with AWS Tools

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, aws-powershell, aws-toolkit

I am writing a powershell script and would like to take advantage of the 7.0 version of Powershell. Specifically because I need access to the new features of CovertFrom-Json that are not available in 5.1. My script has the following command: `get-host | select version`. The log output shows the version is 5.1. The Agent is a windows-2019 (2020 isn't available in the drop down). The task is a ***AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script*** task. Is there a way I can get my script to run in an environment on DevOps to make use of PS 7?

Answer (score 3):

You have it already installed there. Please compare this:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- powershell: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
- pwsh: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
- pwsh: |
    '{ "key":"value1", "Key":"value2" }' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

`powershell` task gives you:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  1852
```

but `pwsh`:

```
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      1      3
```

But `AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script` doesn't support Powershell Core. And looking at [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12872#issuecomment-637751309) that there is no way to replace powershell with pwsh making the second a default shell. In this case I would recommend to create a feature request for `AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script`

However, you can still install AWS Toolkit and use it from pwsh task as follows:

```yaml
- pwsh: Install-Module -name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -Scope CurrentUser -Force
- pwsh: |
    Import-Module AWSPowerShell.NetCore
    Get-Module -ListAvailable

    Get-AWSPowerShellVersion
```